# fixed nav looses focus when scrolling on mobile device

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, fixed

i am having a little problem with a fixed nav on iOS safari.

here is the deal,

the nav works great on desktop, but when i view it on an IOS device it is a little funky.

on portrait view it look / works fine. when i put the phone on landscape view the fixed nav works great until i start scrolling. when i start scrolling the nav button that open the nav looses focus. well the entire nav stays put.

OH i want to point out, this happens on IOS 8, iphone 6 plus, and only when the tables comes out. see the image below.

has anyone seen this? I've looked around and couldn't find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is a really annoying bug with webkit

```
.whatever-your-class-name-is {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

try that. it will fix it.

Comment: should i put that CSS on the actual .nav div ( the container with the fixed position) or the button that opens the nav thats located inside the fixed .nav div. 

i added the css to the .nav container and it didnt work.

Comment: please send example link?